# Nginx - redirect old .php?id=... to SEO friendly url doesn't redirect as expected

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm migrating a website with old-style /category.php?id=4 URLs to /category/seo-friendly-slug URLs.

```
rewrite ^/category.php?id=1$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/pils permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=2$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-blanches permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=4$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/lambics-et-gueuzes permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=5$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/ales-stouts-et-ipa permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=6$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-trappistes permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=7$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-d-abbaye permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=8$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-rouges-des-flandres permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=9$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/lambics-et-gueuzes permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php?id=11$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-fruitees permanent;
rewrite ^/category.php$ /styles-de-bieres-belges permanent;
```

But all `'/category.php?id=...'` requests redirects to `/styles-de-bieres-belges` (the last line). If I remove this last line, it doesn't redirect at all.

What is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using these ifs or that whole bunch of rewrites with similar matching URIs. That will be easier to read and to maintain. This will also avoid a performance hit as rewrite rules regexs are tested sequentially.

Use a **[map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map)** :

```
map $arg_id $target {
    "1"  "pils";
    "2"  "bieres-blanches";
    "4"  "lambics-et-gueuzes";
    "5"  "ales-stouts-et-ipa";
    "6"  "bieres-trappistes";
    "7"  "bieres-d-abbaye";
    "8"  "bieres-rouges-des-flandres";
    "9"  "lambics-et-gueuzes";
    "11" "bieres-fruitees";
}

server {

    ...

    location /category {
        rewrite ^/category.php$ /styles-de-bieres-belges/$target? permanent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier, the performance part is quite important here as I also have redirects for 2'000 beer pages. It works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Query strings are converted to variables in the rewrite rules, and shaved off. For your example, all the rewrite engine sees is `category.php`, but stored values for `$arg_id`.

Try something like this:

```
location = /category.php {
if ($arg_id = "1") {rewrite ^ /styles-de-bieres-belges/pils permanent;}
if ($arg_id = "2") {rewrite ^ /styles-de-bieres-belges/bieres-blanches permanent;}

... the rest of them ...

if ($arg_id !~ "^\d+$") {rewrite ^ /styles-de-bieres-belges permanent;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Hyppy. Didn't know about $arg_{name}, just read the docs about it on http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html. I just had to add a ? at the end of the rewrite to drop the original $args (as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641603/remove-parameters-within-nginx-rewrite).